# Issue in laravel/lumen query builder whereColumn method

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

- Lumen Version: 5.5
- PHP Version: 7.0

I wrote following code to update data by using whereColumn method:

```
Ratings::whereColumn([['class_id', '=', $class_id], ['id', '=', $rating_id]])->update(['grade' => $grade, 'star' => $star, 'comment' => $comment]);
```

which generate a SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'where clause' (SQL: update \`ratings\` set \`grade\` = 16级学生, \`star\` = 4, \`comment\` = very good where (\`class_id\` = \`1\` and \`id\` = \`6\`))
```

it seems that the correct SQL command should use quote '' instead of ``

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

[As per docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

> The whereColumn method may be used to verify that two columns are equal

Therefore it tries to compare column `class_id` with assuming 1 as a column  see back-ticks around 1

Instead use `where` function

```
Ratings::where([['class_id', '=', $class_id], ['id', '=', $rating_id]])
        ->update(['grade' => $grade, 'star' => $star, 'comment' => $comment]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
DB::table('table_name')->where('id','=',$request->input('id'))->update(['name'=>'jijo','address'=>'ernakulam']);
```